# Photo captured using CameraCaptureUI is getting stretched when saving

Tags: c#, image

This is for developing a Windows 10 application.

I am trying to capture an image using the camera, edit the captured image,

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = true;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Windows.Foundation.Size(4, 3);
//captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Windows.Foundation.Size(0,0);
captureUI.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;

StorageFile file = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

This shows up the camera, and I am able to preview and click to capture the image. The captured image is shown in another window over the original camera image windows. I am able to crop and click to save this captured image.

However, right after I click save, the image is getting stretched, and after it is saved, it remains stretched as well. In essence, the image I capture and save is being stretched,

I tried changing the CroppedSizeInPixels with size from (0,0) to (200,200). And also various CroppedAspectRatios.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using any other values for these settings?

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: I am getting the Same issue here. Were you able to find a solution?